# How Can i auto continuous click button by Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I want to constantly click on button id="option2" by greasemonkey.

http://jsfiddle.net/cBJaP/

Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUUo0eguGTg

How can i do it ?

```
<div class="content">
    <ul class="soruBtn">
        <li class="optionA">
            <a id="option1" hidefocus="true" style="outline: medium none;">
                41.000 TL
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="optionB">
             <a id="option2" hidefocus="true" style="outline: medium none;">
                44.000 TL
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".contentContainer").attr("class", "contentContainer2");
</script>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really with either greasemonkey or jQuery, but as I see it this could be solved easily in plain Javascript. Add this code to the `<script>` tag:

```
function pressMyButton(){
    eval(document.getElementById("option2").href);
    setTimeout("pressMyButton()",100);
}
pressMyButton();
```

What this will do: it declares a function `pressMyButton()` (you can choose any name) and in that function it:

1. executes whatever is in the link's `href` attribute
2. calls itself again in 100 milliseconds.

You can of course set the 100 milliseconds to something way smaller but I don't recommend setting it to zero; what are your purposes of repeatedly following/executing the link?

Hope this helped; please let me know if you encounter problems.

Comment: it's not click button. Can you try it your web browser ? Thanks  https://www.facebook.com/sahibindencom/app_112574212172218

Comment: I can see the page, it's a facebook app, but where's the button you want to repeatedly click? And what about it not being a button? What's the problem? Anyway, I'll edit my answer to be about `a`'s and not about `button`'s.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery try something like this:

```
while (true) {
   $('#option2').trigger('click');
}
```

This produces an endless loop that keeps triggering the click event of the button with id option2. Not sure about the greasemonkey part though, no experience with that.

**edit:**

As suggested, adding a timeout is probably best. It would look something like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#option2').trigger('click');
}, 100);
```

This would trigger the click event every 100 msec, or 10 times per second. You could probably increase the speed, depending on your computer and what exactly will be triggered by the button. 
More info about the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: It should work, but I'd suggest `setTimeout` because this might pull too much resources. having a small pause will be better I guess.

Comment: Thanks PeterVR but How can i add settimeout for it ?

Comment: it's not click button. Can you try it your web browser ? Thanks facebook.com/sahibindencom/app_112574212172218

Comment: SO is not a 'free programmers' platform and I am not going to install some facebook app for you, sorry.