# How to repeatedly click a JavaScript link until it disappears?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Some web pages use single-page "pagination" to show more and more of the page with every click, and it is sometimes useful to show all the content on one page (for example for crawling). Similar to [continuously clicking a button in Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813504/how-can-i-auto-continuous-click-button-by-greasemonkey), how can I use JavaScript (for example in the Firefox console) to **find a JavaScript link and click it until the page is fully loaded**? In [this case](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters), "fully loaded" can be defined as either

1. the "Load More" link disappearing or
2. "No videos found at this time." appearing.

I'm not sure which events to listen to on which elements to make this happen efficiently (that is, waiting the minimal amount of time between clicks without busy-waiting). The following code doesn't work, probably since pieces of the page don't have time to load before requesting another one.

```
for (var i=1; i<209; i++) {
    DISCO.video.sort('None','desc',i,'grid');
}
```

Comment: There's not going to be one answer to this question -- it would depend entirely on how the JavaScript running the pagination is set up.

Comment: *until the page is fully loaded* has to be strictly defined. without knowing what indicates that it is fully loaded, we wouldn't know how/when to stop the clicking.

Comment: You could [insert whichever click/pagination action you need per page here] and then check the page height. If it grew since the last check, more items were appended. else, all done.

Comment: @Will Or, it's taking longer than your interval to finish loading more items.

Comment: Ha @kevinB was just going to add that. else... wait some slightly-more-than-reasonable amount of time and try again. :) You'd probably also need to include 'scroll window down to the bottom and wait a bit' for infinite scroll loaders.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but is rather inefficient:

```
function click() {
    var element = $('.sort-assets-action');
    if (typeof element === 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    var action = element.attr('onclick');
    eval(action);
}

setInterval(click, 100);
```